# SharpSnmp v3 GetRequest contains no Variabel Id

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, sharp-snmp

I'm using the ListenerBinding of the SharpSnmp library to receive snmp-get-requests.
The following method handles incoming requests and evaluates the requested id:

```
private void HandleSnmpRequest(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message is GetRequestMessage getRequest){
        var messageId = e.Message.Variables().First().Id;
        ...
    }
    .....
}
```

As long, as the incoming request has the Version 1 or 2 everything is fine.
If the request has the version 3, `e.Message.Variables()` returns an empty collection.
Why isn't the requested id in the "Variables" collection?

Answer (score 0):

The request you got for v3 is the discovery message, which of course does not contain the OID you are looking for.

Sounds like you don't know much about SNMP v3, so I suggest you find a book and learn the concepts before moving on.

In the meantime, processing incoming requests must follow the pipeline pattern, which I documented in [this article](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/samples/agent-development.html).